# How can I solve $\sqrt[x]{x} = const$?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to solve the following equation:

$\sqrt[x]{x} = const$

How does one find $x$ in this case?

Comment: Are you limiting x to real or complex? There are some exact results like $const = 1$, $x =1$. Hint, the solution requires use of the [*Lambert-W function*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html)  Regards

Comment: It doesn't always have solutions, depending on "const". For example: $x=e^x$ has no solutions. For the $a>1$  case: put $f(x)=a^x-x$. We have $f'(x)=\ln a\cdot a^x -1$. The derivative is increasing and $\xi=\log_a(1/ \ln a)$ is a minimum. So we have (note that $1/\ln a=\log_ae)$,  $\min f=f(\xi)=\log_a e-\log_a (\log _a e)$, and: $$f(\xi)\leq 0\iff e \leq \log _a e=1/\ln a$$
Solving for $a$: $$\iff \ln a \leq 1/e \iff a\ \leq e^{1/e}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function $f(x) = x^{1/x}$ has a maximum for $x = e$, is increasing for $0 < x < e$ and decreasing for $x > e$. Finally $f(x) \to 1$ (though slowly) as $x\to\infty$ Hence the equation $f(x) =c$ will have one solution if $x = e^{1/e}$ or $0 < c \le 1$ and two solutions for $1 < c < e^{1/e}$.

For most values of $c$, there will be no simple closed expression for the solution, but one of them is $-W(-\ln c)/\ln c$, where $W$ is the [Lambert function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html).

Here is a plot of $y=f(x)$:

[image]

Comment: The solution with $0 < x \leq e$ is $-W_0(-\log c)/\log c$ and the solution with $x \geq e$ is $-W_{-1}(-\log c)/\log c$, where $W_0$ is the principal branch and $W_{-1}$ is the other real-valued branch of the Lambert function.